# Replacing global vars

Tags: python

Below, I came up with artificially passing the reference var `n2` from `f2()` to `g2(x)` instead of the global var `n` in `f()` and the nested `g()`. Any other better ways to replace global vars in this case?

```
from random import randint

# global value var
def f():
    global n
    n=0    
    def g(): 
        global n
        if randint(1,100)>50: n+=1    
    for _ in range(100): g()
    print(n)

# local reference var
def f2():
    n2=[0]
    for _ in range(100): g2(n2)
    print(n2[0])    
def g2(x):
    if randint(1,100)>50: x[0]+=1
```

Comment: How do you use / call your functions?

Comment: calling `f()`, `f2()`

Comment: What do you mean, artificially? Passing variables into findings is the right thing to do.

Comment: Why can't you pass the initial value of the "global" variable as an argument to the function and then assigns its return value back to the variable? It's hard to answer the question "How do you replace a global variable?" when it's so unclear why you're even using a global variable to begin with.

Comment: I feel OP needs to learn how to use returns. After returning values, call them like `var_f = f(), f2(var_f)` and no need for globals.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, e.g. contrast to languages featuring pointers.

Comment: @Aran-Fey, do you suggest recursive calls?

Comment: If you want to avoid populating the global scope, you can use `nonlocal` inside of `g()` to reference `n` in `f`.  Just remove `global n` from `f` and then in `g` replace `global n` with `nonlocal n`

Comment: @sof No. Why would you need recursive calls?

Comment: Both `n` and `n2` are globals. The difference is that you reassign to the *name* `n` in the first case, but mutate the value referred to by `n2`. (At least, `g2` seems to *want* `n2` to be global; it's local to `f2`.)

Comment: @James, ok, `python 3` has `nonlocal`, neater than `global`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: You are trying to pass by reference an immutable value (integer) and want to update it. Wrapping that in a tiny class, or list, or dict like you're doing is the way to go. But there are other ways if you are able to slightly modify your code.

**Longer answer**: (Note: This might not be a direct answer to your question.)

I understand this is an artificial example. But think about your real problem --Does `g2()` need to know that there is a variable that is supposed to update as a part of its invocation? Is there a way that the responsibility of updating a variable belongs to that which defines it? How about `f2()` is the one that defines the variables and also updates it? That way you can limit all the changes to that variable to a very small perimeter (`f2()`).

My approach in that case would be something like:

```
def f2():
    n2 = 0
    for _ in range(100):
        n2 += g2()
    print(n2)

def g2():
    return 1 if randint(1,100)>50 else 0
```

Comment: `python` is imperative. Coding in it is quite normal without returning values. Should calling to `g2` be deeply routed via many intermediate functions, all of them would have to be refactored according to your proposal.

Comment: @sof: I might not have mentioned it but this is not a rule -- you could use lists as you're doing now, or wrap it in a meaningfully named class. It's just how I think when I write any line of code. In your case, `g2()` need not (and should not) know about state of `n2`. Further, it's your call about refactoring other functions but please think about the benefits too, unit-testing, debugging, idempotence etc. As for your question about `g2` being deeply routed -- I'm not entirely sure I get it.

Answer (score 2):

From working with functional languages, and from trying to write reproducible tests, I've generally tried to adopt a rule that a function should declare all of its inputs as parameters, and produce all of its outputs as return values: to the maximum extent possible a function should never have side effects.  Using the `global` keyword probably indicates you're breaking this rule.

For example, your "g" function takes the current state variable and either increments it or doesn't.  You don't need a global for that (and you don't need it to be a nested function either):

```
from random import randint
def g(n):
    """Returns either n or n+1, with 50% probability."""
    if randint(1,100)>50:
        return n+1
    else:
        return n
```

Then the iterating function can call that a bunch of times:

```
def f():
    """Produces a number between 0 and 100 with $DISTRIBUTION."""
    n = 0
    for _ in range(100):
        n = g(n)
    return n
```

And finally at the top level:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f())
```

Since we're never totally sure about our code, we can write some tests.

```
def test_f():
    n = f()
    assert n >= 0 and n < 100

def test_g():
    n = g(0)
    assert n == 0 or n == 1

def test_g_dist():
    count = 100
    ns = [g(0) for _ in range(count)]
    assert(all(n == 0 or n == 1) for n in ns)
    zeros = len([n for n in ns if n == 0])
    ones = len([n for n in ns if n == 1])
    assert zeros + ones == count
    # won't always pass; probability of failure left as an exercise
    assert zeros > 0.45 * count and zeros < 0.55 * count
```

Notice that I can call `f()` and `g(n)` as many times as I want and they'll never interfere with anything else.  Running my own unit tests at startup time would be a little unusual, but I'm free to if that's what I want to do.

Comment: You have to always pass immutable vars to avoid side effects. Sometimes, the trade-off will cause severe performance penalty even if the more verbose code isn't an issue in an imperative language like `python`.

Comment: Your first paragraph deserves much more upvotes! You expressed what I wanted to in clearer words :)